# Wireshark, simple way to find http request posts

Tags: http-post, httprequest, wireshark, http-request

I am curently trying to find out a way to detect HTTP requests and posts from FACEBOOK.COM ONLY.

But i cant find it in the "filter" area.
Is there any way to see only requests and posts from facebook??

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Since Facebook is using HTTPS you won't be able to get the requests using Wireshark. To capture those requests you can use your browser's console.

Comment: Chrome browser doesnt show me all the https requests/posts... any other suggestions?